# Yii, Php, mPDF, generating a pdf with widgets of different orientations

Tags: php, pdf, yii, mpdf

I am implementing an application in **Yii php**, and I am trying **to make PDFs** using the **mPDF extension.**

I'm generating a sort of **Summary Report** where I make a pdf for it. Inside the generated pdf **are 3 widgets,** basically tables to create that report.

Here's how it looks:

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A5');
..
..//set mpdf properties etc..

$mPDF1->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);

$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html1,2);
//say $html1 is a widget/table  with a portrait orientation

$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html2,2);
//$html2 is a widget/table with a portrait orientation

$mPDF1->WriteHTML(&html3,2);
//$html3 is a widget/table that needs to have a landscape orientation because it's too long.

//and then output the pdf and so on..
```

Above code works, **but displays the tables all in a portrait orientation**, I need to display the table in **$html3 in a landscape orientation.** Is there a way to do this?mpdF properties I guess or something. And also, is is there a way to separate `$html3` and have it on **the start of the next page** in the same PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to AddPage with Landscape orientation:

```
$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html2,2);
//$html2 is a widget/table with a portrait orientation

$mPDF1->AddPage('L');
$mPDF1->WriteHTML(&html3,2);
```

Comment: Just a follow up question sir, how do i make the PDF page to be still portrait while making the contents only to be landscaped.

Comment: the above code is correct, however is it possible that i have a continuous PDF file in all in portrait but, the contents inside it are actually in landscape orientation?

Comment: Well, U may try TCPDF, I don't remember has it a same trouble or not.